# Error FILE, al intentar cargar flutter

Tags: flutter

Cordial saludo, requiero ayuda para lograr resolver este error, no encuentro documentación y todos realizan la tarea así, estoy pendiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Subir imágenes de código y de mensajes de error [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). ¿Qué mensaje aparece cuando colocas el puntero encima de esa variable? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te indica que esa variable está declarada como No-nula, por lo tanto está esperando un valor de inicialización, tienes varias opciones.

- Declara tu variable como optional.

```dart
File? sampleImage;
```

o

- Adiciona la palabra `late`.

```dart
late File sampleImage;
```

Te recomiendo este codelab de null safety: https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety

Si quieres conocer Flutter avanzado, revisa mi canal en youtube (con el mismo nombre :))